В python записать в csv разбив строку на колонки
  import csv
line = "1,10019,rs775809821,TA,T,.,.,RS=775809821"
columns = line.split(',')
output_csv_file_path = 'C:/Users/1/out122put.csv'
with open(output_csv_file_path, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(columns)

print(f"Данные успешно сохранены в файл {output_csv_file_path}")

Но почему то данные по колонкам не разбиваются


csv - это текстовый формат файла. текст вы записываете правильный. а на картинке нарисовали что-то несоответствующее тексту. возможно, в той программе, с помощью которой рисовали картинку, вы указали в качестве разделителя не запятую, а другой символ.

Можно было вообще просто поменять символы , на ; и записать в файл эту строку, без всяких csvwrigher-ов. )  Это обычный текстовый файл, как уже написали.

Код выглядит рабочим. Проблема скорее всего в том, что вы открываете .csv файл в excel не как .csv файл. А если и открываете, то скорее всего excel ожидает другой разделитель на колонки (точку с запятой скорее всего), с этим можно поиграться в настройках.
Вот такое изменение должно помочь:
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')


Так получилось. спасибо)
